# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '('

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

I have to read a multivalue field in oracle and values are of float type.i have to find all the rows with field value having 3.1.

So my HQL query is

```
select d.NAME, d.FLOATCOMMA_MV from cc_mv_test d where :param1 in elements (TO_BINARY_FLOAT(d.FLOATCOMMA_MV))
```

and after using **TO_BINARY_FLOAT** i am getting error
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1.

Please help.

Comment: show how you call the query in java method

Comment: Hi I have created the query using session.createQuery() method and then called the list() method on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a native query, not HQL.

Use `session.createSQLQuery("query").list()` method.

Keep in mind that the return type will be `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: Hi sorry! my mistake. I actually pasted the entire sql. Hql query i am using is following "from cc_mv_test d where :param1 in elements (d.FLOATCOMMA_MV)" .

Comment: Hence I am using session.createquery().list().and facing the problem..then how to fix?